# Why is my custom taxonomy image not displaying?

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, terms, taxonomy-meta

I have created a custom image taxonomy field in WordPress using CMB2. I cannot get the images to display for website visitors even though my code uses **get_term_meta**. (The taxonomy images are amenity icons such as WiFi, shower head, electricity etc).

What am I doing wrong?

Relevant (not working) code in single-accommodation.php:

```
<?php
$term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$tax_image = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'custom_taxonomy_image', true );

if ( $tax_image ) {
    printf( '<div class="icon"><img src=$s /></div>', $tax_image );
}
?>
```

I'm sure i'd need a foreach somewhere, like this:

```
<ul class="amenity-icons">
<?php
foreach( $terms as $term => $icon ) {
   if( isset( $term ) ) {
      echo '<li>' . $icon . '</li>';
   }
}
?>
</ul>
```

I can successfully retrieve the term list as words using:

```
<?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'amenity' ); ?>
```

Comment: i hope this works for you. use like this.
printf( "<div class=icon ><img src=%s  /></div>", $tax_image );

Comment: you are using " $ " in printf you should use % instead of $.  "  src=%s  "  instead of "  src=$s  ".

Answer (score 0):

Use printf with an img tag and `wp_get_attachment_image_src`

```
<?php
$term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$tax_image = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'custom_taxonomy_image', true );
$image_id = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $tax_image, 'full' );

if ( $image_id ) {
printf( '<div class="icon"><img src=$s /></div>', $image_id );
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Shawn. Nothing at all is showing, though... do I need to combine this with my working line of code somehow? It doesn't mention my custom taxonomy **'amenity'** currently.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks again, Shawn. Still nothing. Should I be adjusting the $term_id variable to mention my custom taxonomy?

Comment: Hmm, try it and see if that works.

Comment: Sadly it still doesn't. Can you see how I might need to include a reference to my custom taxonomy? (Like the working line of code)

Comment: Are you sure the meta key is correct 'custom_taxonomy_image' ?

Comment: Have you also tried using get_queried_object_id() instead of get_queried_object()?

Comment: Yes, meta key is correct.  Adding get_queried_object_id() now gives this error:  `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ... single-accommodation.php on line 17`  The newly edited $term_id() line.

Comment: and also 'undefined variable' error. Puzzling!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the code on a single post page, then these are both empty:

```
$term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id; // ''
$tax_image = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'custom_taxonomy_image', true ); // false
```

because on single post pages, `get_queried_object()` is a post object and not a term object.

And if this works well on that page:

```
<?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'amenity' ); ?>
```

Then you can loop through `get_the_terms()` like so, to display the custom term icon:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'amenity' );
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $icon = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'custom_taxonomy_image', true );
        echo '<li>' . $icon . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

If the value of the `custom_taxonomy_image` field is *not* an `<img>` tag, then you can manually generate the `<img>` tag, or use [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/) if the value is an attachment ID.

- If `$icon` is an image URL:

  ```
  echo '<li><img src="' . esc_url( $icon ) . '" /></li>';
  ```
- If `$icon` is an attachment ID:

  ```
  echo '<li>' . wp_get_attachment_image( $icon ) . '</li>';
  ```

### UPDATE

*Removed, but you can always check the answer's revisions.*

### UPDATE #2

The original answer was meant to show how can you loop through the post terms (which retrieved via `get_the_terms()`) to retrieve the meta value via `get_term_meta()`. Now via this update, I hope you can properly display the custom term icon(s).

- If the field value is an *array of attachment ID => image URL*, where the value looks like: ***(this is specific to the [`file_list`](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/Field-Types#file_list) field in CMB2)***

  ```
  array(
      123 => 'Original image URL',
      456 => 'Original image URL',
      ...
  )
  ```

  then:

  ```
  // Here the field name is assumed custom_taxonomy_images
  $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'amenity' );
  if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
      foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
          $icons = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'custom_taxonomy_images', true );

          $list = array();
          foreach ( (array) $icons as $id => $url ) {
              if ( ! $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $id, array( 24, 24 ) ) ) {
                  $image = 'Default icon here';
              }
              $list[] = $image;
          }

          echo '<li>' . implode( ' ', $list ) . '</li>';
      }
  }
  ```
- If the field value is an *image URL*:

  ```
  // Here the field name is assumed custom_taxonomy_image_url
  $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'amenity' );
  if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
      foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
          $url = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'custom_taxonomy_image_url', true );
          $url = $url ? $url : 'http://example.com/default-image-url.jpg';
          echo '<li><img src="' . esc_url( $url ) . '" width="24"></li>';
      }
  }
  ```
- If the field value is an *attachment ID*:

  ```
  // Here the field name is assumed custom_taxonomy_image_id
  $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'amenity' );
  if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
      foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
          $id = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'custom_taxonomy_image_id', true );
          if ( ! $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $id, array( 24, 24 ) ) ) {
              $image = 'Default icon here';
          }
          echo '<li>' . $image . '</li>';
      }
  }
  ```

*Note: The value `24` (pixels) is just an example width/height.*

Comment: I really appreciate the comprehensive reply, Sally!  Unfortunately, your main loop above returns an `Array to string conversion` notice on line 22 (with the $icon).

Comment: Replacing that line with image URL displays `Warning: stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ../wp-includes/formatting.php` error. 
Replacing with attachment ID displays no errors but crucially no icons.

Comment: What is `var_dump( $icon )`? You basically just need to identify the proper array key and do something like `$icon['THE KEY']`.

Comment: var_dump ($icon) gives: `array(1) { [572]=> string(89) "http://path/to/image.jpg" }`

Comment: Check updated answer. But why not use the `file` (i.e. single image) type for the term icon? Check [this](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/Field-Types#file).

Comment: Hi Sally. Using file displays some similar errors in the admin (an issue with cmb2 and php 7.2 I think). However, the field still works, but using `$image = wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_taxonomy_image_id', 1 ), 'medium' );` nothing is displayed.

Comment: Maybe because you used `get_post_meta()` and not `get_term_meta()`. But anyway, please check the updated answer and let me know.